# Unable to map columns automatically from source csv files to Azure synapse table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am creating a dynamic mapping data flow pipeline. My objective is to load the .csv file which is a  parameter and load into Azure SQL data pool table(table name is also a parameter). for this i created a target dataset with type azure synapse analytics & source dataset as .csv type.
And i didnt import any schema in source and target datasets.

I have checked Schema drift option in both the source & sink transformations.

But i am experiencing  issue in sink transformation, with the error message  below

" The result has 0 output columns .Please ensure at least one column is mapped."

I didnt see this issue when i do fixed mapping. when i am doing auto mapping this pipeline is failing with above error.

So is this a technical limitation in Azure Synapse Analytics type data set?

Please let me know any suggestions to fix this.

Comment: Please check the dataset schema, clear the schema import.

Comment: i have clear the schema import. no luck.

Comment: Try to have schema imported in source and sink datasets from storage/connection or from a local sample file. If source and sink column names are not similar then Auto mapping feature in Sink transformation will not work. In that scenario you need to disable auto mapping to map them correctly.